# Django: When do I need __eq__ method?

Tags: python, django

In Django I've written a custom class-based validator and implemented the `__eq__` method because it's also done for the validators that are already implemented by Django itself.

Here you can see it:

```
@deconstructible
class FileSizeValidator:

    def __init__(self, mb):
        self.mb = mb

    def __call__(self, value):
        limit = self.mb * 1024 * 1024
        if value.size > limit:
            raise ValidationError('File too big (max. ' + str(self.mb) + ' MiB).')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            isinstance(other, FileSizeValidator) and
            self.mb == other.mb
        )
```

Now, I've also written a custom class for the `ImageField`. I want to use it for the `upload_to=` parameter in a model for the `ImageField`. Here you can see my example:

```
@deconstructible
class RandomFileName:

    def __init__(self, directory=''):
        self.directory = directory

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        return self.directory + ("/" if self.directory else '') + get_random_string(7) + "." + filename.split('.')[-1]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            isinstance(other, RandomFileName) and
            self.directory == other.directory
        )
```

In general, I am happy with it and it seems to work fine. I just do not know **when** I need the `__eq__` method and would like to ask you for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is called operator overloading and in your example, it's for comparing two objects. After implementing `__eq__()` method, you can compare any other object for equality with your object.

We can now create two objects from your class:

```
obj1 = FileSizeValidator(100)
obj2 = FileSizeValidator(200)
```

and can compare them as `obj1 == obj2`.

Since we have custom `__eq__()` defined, this would compare the `class` of the object and the value of `mb` attribute to return a `True` or `False` value. If any of the condition fails, it will return `False`.

By default in python an equality operator for two custom objects compares the `id` values of the objects and would never return `True` except when comparing an object with itself.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I just wonder WHEN and WHY I need those methods?

Comment: @Aliquis When you want to compare two objects with a custom condition like in this one you are matching the value of `mb` attribute. There can be 10 more attributes with un-matched values but nothing else matters if this value matches.

Comment: Let me ask in another way: Why does Django implement __eq__ for its validators?

Comment: In python, by default no two custom class objects will be equal to each other. An object will be equal to itself only. So to compare two objects for equality, you need to overload equality operator.

Comment: So I wonder if I should override the `__eq__` method for the RandomFileName class?

Comment: No, if you do not expect two objects of this class to be compared.